# MySQL Query Optimization that touches three tables via a union of two of them

Tags: mysql, optimization, pagination

I have a query that returns results from a single table based on the provided ID existing in a column in one of two, or both, tables. The DB schema for the relevant tables is provided below as well as the initial query and then what was later recommended to me by a peer. I go into some details below as to why this query works but I need to optimize it farther for larger datasets and pagination.

```
CREATE TABLE `killmails` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `hash` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `moon_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `solar_system_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `war_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `is_npc` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `is_awox` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `is_solo` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `dropped_value` DECIMAL(18,4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    `destroyed_value` DECIMAL(18,4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    `fitted_value` DECIMAL(18,4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    `total_value` DECIMAL(18,4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    `killmail_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `hash`),
    INDEX `total_value` (`total_value`),
    INDEX `killmail_time` (`killmail_time`),
    INDEX `solar_system_id` (`solar_system_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `killmail_attackers` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `killmail_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `alliance_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `character_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `corporation_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `faction_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `damage_done` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `final_blow` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `security_status` DECIMAL(17,15) NOT NULL,
    `ship_type_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `weapon_type_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `ship_type_id` (`ship_type_id`),
    INDEX `weapon_type_id` (`weapon_type_id`),
    INDEX `alliance_id` (`alliance_id`),
    INDEX `corporation_id` (`corporation_id`),
    INDEX `killmail_id_character_id` (`killmail_id`, `character_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `killmail_attackers_killmail_id_killmails_id_foreign_key` FOREIGN KEY (`killmail_id`) REFERENCES `killmails` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `killmail_victim` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `killmail_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `alliance_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `character_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `corporation_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `faction_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `damage_taken` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `ship_type_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `ship_value` DECIMAL(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    `pos_x` DECIMAL(30,10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pos_y` DECIMAL(30,10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pos_z` DECIMAL(30,10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `corporation_id` (`corporation_id`),
    INDEX `alliance_id` (`alliance_id`),
    INDEX `ship_type_id` (`ship_type_id`),
    INDEX `killmail_id_character_id` (`killmail_id`, `character_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `killmail_victim_killmail_id_killmails_id_foreign_key` FOREIGN KEY (`killmail_id`) REFERENCES `killmails` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

This first query is where the problem started:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM  
    killmails k
    LEFT JOIN killmail_attackers ka ON k.id = ka.killmail_id
    LEFT JOIN killmail_victim kv ON k.id = kv.killmail_id
WHERE 
    ka.character_id = ? 
    OR kv.character_id = ?
ORDER BY killmails.killmail_time DESC
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

This worked okay, but long query times. We optimized to this

```
SELECT
    killmails.*,
FROM (
    SELECT killmail_victim.killmail_id FROM killmail_victim
        WHERE killmail_victim.corporation_id = ?
    UNION
    SELECT killmail_attackers.killmail_id FROM killmail_attackers
        WHERE killmail_attackers.corporation_id = ?
) SELECTED_KMS
LEFT JOIN killmails ON killmails.id = SELECTED_KMS.killmail_id
ORDER BY killmails.killmail_time DESC
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

I saw a huge improvement in query times when looking up killmails for characters, however when I started querying for larger datasets like corporation and alliance killmails, the query slows down. This is because the queries that are union'd together can potentially return large sets of data and the time it takes to read all that into memory so that the SELECTED_KMS table can be created is what I believe is taking so much time. Most of the time, with alliances, my connection to the database times out from the application. One alliance returned 900K killmailIDs from one of the union'd tables, not sure what the other returned.

I can easily add limit statements to the internal queries, but this will introduce a lot of complications when I get to paginating the data or when I introduce a feature to search for KMs by date for example.

I am looking for suggestions on how this query can be optimized and still allow for easy pagination in the near future.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `INDEX(corporation_id)` in both tables to `INDEX(corporation_id, killmail_id)` so that the inner queries will be "covering".

In general, `INDEX(a)` is useless when you also have `INDEX(a,b)`.  Any query that needs just `a`, can use either of those indexes.  (This rule does not apply to `b`; only the "leftmost" column(s).)

Where does `killmails.id` come from?  It's not `AUTO_INCREMENT`; it is not alone in the `PRIMARY KEY`, so there is no specified "uniqueness" constraint.  Is it unique by some other design?  Is it computed somewhere else in the code?  (I ask because I need a feel for its uniqueness and other characteristics.)

Add `INDEX(id, killmails_time)`.

What version are you using?

Perhaps `UNION ALL` give the same results?  It would be faster because it would not need to de-dup.

How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Do you really need 8-byte `BIGINTs`?  Even if your application is using longlong (or whatever it calls it), you can *probably* change the schema without changing the app.

Do you need this much precision and range?  `DECIMAL(30,10)` -- it takes 14 bytes each.  `DOUBLE` would give you about 16 *significant* digits in 8 bytes, with a wider range of values (up to about 10^308).  What "units" are you using?  (Overkill for light-years or parsecs; inadequate for miles or km.  Perhaps AUs?  Then the bottom digit would be a precision of a few meters?)

The last few questions are aimed at shrinking the table and seeing if we can avoid it being as I/O-bound as it apparently is now.

**Important**

`innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M` is terribly small, especially for a 32GB machine, and especially if your dataset is much bigger than 128MB.  If there are not any other apps running on the server, bump that setting up to `20G`.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. Some follow up questions

RE: `INDEX(corporation_id, killmail_id)` do I need to keep the initial index on just corporation_id around or can I remove it?

RE: `killmails.id` can you clarify? It is the primary key on the killmails table and what relates killmail_victim and killmail_attacker together.

RE Version: MySQL 5.7
RE UNION ALL: Intentionally using UNION for the deduplication of the ids
RE RAM: 32GB and I have not seen this spike above 3GB since I started on this project
RE Precision and Range: Yes these are coordinates within the universe

Comment: RE Big Ints: Probably not, I was being lazy when I designed the DB honestly. I would rather try the other recommended changes to the index first as changing those types will require an update to the application hitting this as well, however I am not opposing it completely.

Comment: RE what is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`
mysql>  SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024;
+-------------------------------------+
| @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024 |
+-------------------------------------+
|                        128.00000000 |
+-------------------------------------+

Comment: @DevOverlord - I edited my Answer in several places.

Comment: thanks for the edits. The killmail id is guaranteed to be unique in the killmails table. I simply created the primary key on the id and hash because they come from the API as a package, that is it. I've bumped the pool_size to 20G, the query is now sub 1 minute, as opposed to the 2.5 minutes it previously took. Ill look at the schema changes

Comment: I do want to ask though, is there no way to efficiently limit the results that we are getting back from the sub queries? The attackers query for an alliance using alliance_id return 5.5 million rows and the victim returns just under 1 mil rows of ids, but only need between 100- 500 at a time, total. This is probably a really bad query

Comment: also, the database is over 80GB without indexes

Comment: @DevOverlord - Seems like this should work:  `... FROM ( SELECT ... LIMIT 100 ) x JOIN ...`  Since you have a `UNION`, there may need to be an extra pair of parens.  For pagination of `UNIONs`, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination#pagination_and_union

Comment: That helped. I decided to reduce the pool back down to 5G since the limits are in place now, remove all of the single column indexes and replace with the double column indexes on killmail_id on killmail_attackers and killmail_victim. thank you so much for your assistance.